# Flutter's readAsBytes is very slow on iOS device

Tags: dart, flutter

Running the following code is very slow on iOS device although it is fast on iOS simulator.

The file comes from its album.

How can I speed it up?

```
  Future<List<int>> decoding(File f) async {
    return await f.readAsBytes();
  }
```

Comment: What does "very slow" mean exactly? What iOS device? How big is the file?

Comment: It takes more than 10 seconds. The file size is around 1MB.

Comment: How long does it take on the emulator? How long does it take on Android? (if you can test) Where is the file stored?

Comment: I guess it's best to create a bug report in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues, but please try to answer above questions when you do.

Comment: On emulator, less than 1 second. The file is stored at camera roll on iOS.
I have not tested on Android yet..

Comment: Do you know there is a workaround to run the function on another thread or process?

Comment: You'd usually do it in an isolate with Dart.

Comment: Any solutions ?

Comment: I'm having a problem with similar thing. I'm reading a file using `final fileBytes = await rootBundle.load(file);`. On Android, for 1MB file, it takes around 90ms, on iOS the same thing and the same file takes around 7 seconds. Something is really wrong with Flutters file/bytes handling on iOS.